# Why I'm getting memory leaks with xmlTextReaderConstValue?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios

I'm writing my own wrapper class for parsing XML data. Usually I use the Leak Performance Tool to detect suspicios behaviour through forgetting to release allocated memory.
At this time I figured out that the following code (the first line becomes marked by the tool) brings me an enormous memory leak (leaks more the bigger the XML data file becomes).
the following part is used to receive the text inside a Node.

```
NSString *currentTagValue = [NSString stringWithCString:(char *)xmlTextReaderConstValue(XMLReader) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"set%@:", [currentTag capitalizedString]]);
[currentItem performSelector:selector withObject:currentTagValue];
```

If I add

```
[currentTagValue release]
```

the memory leaks are gone.

This seems strange to me, because I don't allocate memory for the NSString manually. That's why I thought it would be autoreleased.
The whole situation becomes stranger if I compare the upper code example with the part that is responsible for obtaining the node name.

```
NSString *currentTagName = [NSString stringWithCString:(char *)xmlTextReaderConstName(XMLReader) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"set%@:", [currentTagName capitalizedString]]);
```

Here I dont't have to add a manual release, everything works fine and I'm getting no memory leak.
I'm not sure if my described problem is a side-effect of the xml...ConstValue function (the working part uses xml...ConstName) or if the reason is the performed selector afterwards.

Thanks for reading, I hope anyone can explain it to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using libxml2? I haven't used libxml2 yet, but I googled quickly and found this:
http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlreader.html

> Function: xmlTextReaderConstValue
>
> Returns:  the string or NULL if not
>   available. **The result will be
>   deallocated on the next Read()
>   operation**.

Compare that with xmlTextReaderConstName

> Function: xmlTextReaderConstName
>
> Returns:  the local name or NULL if not
>   available, **the string is deallocated
>   with the reader**.

It may be a leak in the lib, or a false alarm as the result seems to be on a delayed release (or something entirely different as I have no firsthand experience to say otherwise). Is the program crashing because of the leak or not? If it is not, maybe it's just a false alarm.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm sure this is the point. The App doesn't crash upon this leak. Thanks for documentation link.